# Почему говорят "басурман"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Раньше иноземцев, особенно выходцев с Востока, называли **басурманами**.
Откуда в русском языке взялось это слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово **басурманин** имеет такую ближайшую этимологию: бусурман "нехристь, мусульманин", др.-русск. бесурменинъ. Заимств. из тат., казах. musulman, тур. mµslim, mµslµm„n, народн. mµsµrman. Особенно близки русск. формам тюрк. формы с b-, напр. кирг. busurman, кумык., балкар. busurman. b- имеется также в кыпч. и волжскоболг. Источником этих слов является перс. muslimaІn (мн.) из араб. muslim. Ср. также *бесерменин* - в настоящее время название *бесермяне* носит ассимилированная удмуртами тюрк. этническая группа на р. Чепце (Фасмер).